# mate-terminal colour scheme partially broken after stretch upgrade

Tags: terminal, vim, colors, mate, debian-stretch

I upgraded a system from jessie to stretch the "Dark Yellow" colour from the palette does not appear to be used in Vim (either the new Vim in stretch or a different vim on a remote host). Instead of the colour I specify in the palette under Profile Preferences, a dark orange is used. I can change all colours in the palette, and most of them immediately take effect in the colourscheme, yet some are ignored:

[image: Colours]

Next to using the colour name 'DarkYellow' I also tried [numerical colours](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html#cterm-colors), which seem to not match the documentation. I can only select 'Yellow' or 'LightYellow'.

This worked correctly before the upgrade to stretch.

Is this a bug in mate-terminal, or am I doing something wrong to access the system palette?

Answer (score 0):

`mate-terminal` uses the `VTE` terminal emulation widget, which supports an extended 256-color palette (as pretty much every graphical terminal emulator does today; and by the way, `VTE` even supports direct true colors). The first 16 entries of that palette (the legacy ones) can be configured in its Preferences dialog, the rest cannot.

`mate-terminal` also exports `TERM=xterm-256color` by default, so `vim` is aware that it supports 256 colors and picks a color scheme accordingly.

A possible workaround is to revert to only 16 colors by not letting `vim` know that the terminal emulator supports more, you can do this by `export TERM=xterm`. I'd rather suggest though to look around in vim's settings and configure it to use your desired colors even when it knows that 256 colors are available.